# How should I display more clearly long text/options/answers on a mobile form (currently its a dropdown)?

Tags: forms, mobile, drop-down-list

I am working on a mobile form and some questions have dropdowns with long input text. Users can't read the entire answers and I can't reduce the text more than I already did. Unfortunately, I have that limitation.

Should I change it to radio buttons (one of them has 7 options) or is there any other way around it?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you provide any samples of this text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This image isn't the best example (I'll try to make a nicer one) but I think if you make each "radio button" in the list into a large selectable item... it should be easy to select and also to read all the details of what you are selecting...

e.g.

[image]

I would just make sure that (however you build it) that only 1 item is selectable and that it is visually obvious that it is selected.